# Geometric interpretation of k-th power of first n natural numbers and summation using Pick's theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, sequences-and-series, lattices

I want to know is there any interesting properties of this approach or generalization to find  $S_k(n)=1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+n^k$ by using Pick's Theorem $S=i+\tfrac{b}{2}-1$, where $i$-number of interior points and $b$ - number of boundary points and the following geometric interpretation:

$(\textbf{1})$ - Let consider $S_1(n)$ then for first steps:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n& b_n & i_n \\ \hline
 1& 4& 0\\ \hline
 2&  8& 0\\ \hline
 3&  12& 1\\ \hline
 4&  16& 3\\ \hline
 5&  20& 6\\ \hline
 ...&  ...& ...\\ \hline
 n&  4n& \tfrac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}\\ \hline
\end{array}

$(\textbf{2})$ - Let consider $S_2(n)$ then for first steps:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n& b_n & i_n \\ \hline
 1& 4& 0\\ \hline
 2&  10& 1\\ \hline
 3&  18& 6\\ \hline
 4&  28& 17\\ \hline
 5&  40& 36\\ \hline
 ...&  ...& ...\\ \hline
 n&  n(n+3)& \tfrac{(n-1)(n^2+n-3)}{3}\\ \hline
\end{array}

$(\textbf{3})$ - Let consider $S_3(n)$ then for first steps:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n& b_n & i_n \\ \hline
 1& 4& 0\\ \hline
 2&  14& 3\\ \hline
 3&  30& 22\\ \hline
 4&  52& 75\\ \hline
 ...&  ...& ...\\ \hline
 n&  n(3n+1)& \tfrac{(n-1)(n+1)(n^2+2n-4)}{4}\\ \hline
\end{array}
$...$

$(\textbf{k})$ - Let consider $S_k(n)$ :$\textbf{???}$
[image]
 So, $\textbf {the questions}$ are: How to find general formulas for $b_n$ and $i_n$ for any step $k$ when we depict our sums as follows: $S_k(n)=1^2\cdot1^{k-2}+2^2\cdot2^{k-2}+3^2\cdot3^{k-2}+...+n^2\cdot n^{k-2}$ - so $n^{k-2}$ times we take $n^2$ and add belows the previous squares? And, the second question: are such constructions involved in any math research or have some interesting properties?

Comment: You have geometric interpretations for $S_k(n)$, as illustrated in this video (in french though). https://www.lebesgue.fr/video/5min/pierre

Comment: Here is another one (for low k): https://nrich.maths.org/5435